# Usage of なら in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles

I came across this sentence recently:

> 日本語ならちょっと喋れるよ

The translation given was 'I speak a little Japanese.'

I am struggling to understand how なら functions as a particle here, since from what I have read it implies a sort of uncertainty (i.e. X なら Y implies if X, then Y) but that doesn't seem appropriate in this case.

Comment: The translation given looks pretty half-baked in that it flatly ignores the function of なら from the original.  Contrary to how you seem to feel, the なら in the original definitely has the sense of "if".

Comment: The reason for using なら should be found in the context/situation in which this sentence appears.

Comment: @l'électeur unfortunately, this was a sentence without context, given as an example of the use of 「ちょっと」.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This なら is a topic marker that functions to draw the listener's attention to the thing being discussed. It might be easier to understand this 「なら」 along the lines of "when it comes to" or "as for". See [entry 2 on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89):

> 2 A topic marker.
> 花なら桜だ。
> As for flowers, the best is the cherry blossom.
>
> 風景ならスイスに及ぶ国はない。
> As for landscape, there isn't a country comparable to Switzerland.

Personally when it comes to translating or explaining the topic marker I prefer "when it comes to", or "in terms of", or "speaking of", etc. to "as for" depending the context, because "as for" in a lot of sentences sounds too ambiguous for my taste, but that's probably just me.

> 日本語ならちょっと喋れるよ

could be rendered as

> If we are talking about Japanese (if you are asking about Japanese), I can speak a little.

Comment: Thank you! But why use なら rather than the topic marker は？

Comment: @jumbot 「なら」sounds more tentative, to me anyway. Check out this answer by l'électeur [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21372/30454)